# XSLT sorting by 2 tags on the same level

Tags: xslt

I have the xml which I need to sort by 2 tags: Type and NonRecurringCharges. The value of Type tag is not unique (there are 2 Product in my xml). The NonRecurringCharges tag can be missed in any Offerings. I've written XLT template but it doesn't change anything in the original xml.

Hopefully someone can help with this.

XML:

```
<ContractSummary>
<OrderInfo>
    <IsMobileOnly>false</IsMobileOnly>
</OrderInfo>
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product</Type>
    <Name Language="NL">Cable Access</Name>
    <NonRecurringCharges>
        <Type>PostPaid</Type>
        <ThirdPartyFinancingId>CAAC0001</ThirdPartyFinancingId>
    </NonRecurringCharges>
</Offerings>
    <Offerings>
    <Type>OneTimeService</Type>
    <Name Language="NL">Cable Access</Name>
    <NonRecurringCharges>
        <Type>PostPaid</Type>
        <ThirdPartyFinancingId>CAAC0001</ThirdPartyFinancingId>
    </NonRecurringCharges>
</Offerings>
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product</Type>
    <Name Language="ZFR">Enlvement</Name>
</Offerings></ContractSummary>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="Offerings">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
    <xsl:sort select="Type"  />
    <xsl:sort select="NonRecurringCharges"  />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>   </xsl:template>
```

I need xml:

```
<ContractSummary>
<OrderInfo>
    <IsMobileOnly>false</IsMobileOnly>
</OrderInfo>
<Offerings>
    <Type>OneTimeService</Type>
    <Name Language="NL">Cable Access</Name>
    <NonRecurringCharges>
        <Type>PostPaid</Type>
        <ThirdPartyFinancingId>CAAC0001</ThirdPartyFinancingId>
    </NonRecurringCharges>
</Offerings>
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product</Type>
    <Name Language="ZFR">Enlvement</Name>
</Offerings>
<Offerings>
    <Type>Product2</Type>
    <Name Language="NL">Cable Access</Name>
    <NonRecurringCharges>
        <Type>PostPaid</Type>
        <ThirdPartyFinancingId>CAAC0001</ThirdPartyFinancingId>
    </NonRecurringCharges>
</Offerings>
```

Comment: It looks like you want to sort the `Offerings` elements that are children of the `ContractSummary` elements so you will somehow need to sort when processing the `Offerings` elements with `apply-templates`, not when processing their child elements. How complex and variable is the XML input, in your sample the `Offerings` elements are preceded by one sibling `OrderInfo`? Is that the only sibling and will it always be the first child element of `ContractSummary`? And of course as always, state which XSLT processor and/or XSLT version you use.

Comment: The original xml has more than 250 rows and yes, it is complex. The OrderInfo tag is not only one sibling, there is one more, but both of them have complex tree (about 30 rows) instead of the simple IsMobileOnly tag. About XSLT version - I need time to check it.

Comment: I have 2.0 XSLT version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="ContractSummary">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *[not(self::Offerings)]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Offerings">
        <xsl:sort select="Type"  />
        <xsl:sort select="NonRecurringCharges"  />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>   
</xsl:template>
```

might make more sense and might suffice if you know that the other children of `ContractSummary` precede all `Offerings` elements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I've got error "The end-tag for element type `xsl:template` must end with a `>` delimiter." Have you any ideas why?

Comment: @user2489599, no idea, I don't see anything wrong with the code I posted in the answer. You haven't shown any sample that produces that problem. Raise it as a separate question if you can't figure it out on your own.

Comment: the previous error was my mistake in xml document. I apologize for incorrect work with your template. Now I don't have any error but I have the resulted xml with 1 ContractSummary tag and all tags' values inside it: <ContractSummary>falseOneTimeServiceCable AccessPostPaidCAAC0001ProductEnlvementProductCable AccessPostPaidCAAC0001</ContractSummary>. I would appreciate if you help me figure out how I can get the xml with sorted tags and its values (see the 'I need xml:' in my question).

Comment: You need to keep the first template from your own code around together with the template from the answer.

Comment: Thank you Martin! You're simple the best!)

Comment: Would you so kind to answer the last my question about this template? If I add some attributes to ContractSummary tag then the template doesn't change the original xml.
My ContactSummary is like that: <ContractSummary xmlns="ContractSummary" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="ContractSummary schema.xsd"> .......</ContractSummary

Comment: That is the usual problem with a default namespace, easily fixed in XSLT 2 or 3 by adding `xpath-default-namespace="ContractSummary"` to the `xsl:stylesheet` element. For XSLT 1, see any similar question on how to deal with a default namespace declaration.

Comment: @IdurJul, if your question is solved by an answer then it is common practice on stackoverflow that you accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer.